# How to redeploy WAR inside a JBoss WildFly container?

Tags: maven, docker, jakarta-ee, wildfly, development-environment

I am trying to make my local Java development environment more lighter.
**Dockerfile** multi-stage steps looks like this:

```
MAVEN CONTAINER
  build app from source code

WILDFLY CONTAINER
  prepare server (data sources, drivers)
  copy WAR from MAVEN
  start server and deploy application
```

This usually takes about 1-3 minutes, even with dependencies-offline-mode.

After making some code changes I have two options - build new image (1-3 minutes) or manually build WAR and redeploy app from WildFly Administration Panel. Is there any tool to automate this?
**Maybe this basic approach will be enough:**

```
0. start local env as always
1. make some code changes
2. build WAR in MAVEN conotainer
3. copy WAR into WILDFLY container
4. enter WILDFLY container bash and redeploy using JBOSS-CLI
```

Are you using some Maven plugins? Bash scripts? **Thank you for hints!**

Comment: The [Maven WildFly plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/) has everything you need. You can add a `wildfly-deploy` profile in you Maven build and use the same container configuration you use for the build above to deploy directly to the running WildFly container - just make sure the Maven container can talk to the WildFly container on the administration port (9990 by default).

Comment: Also Eclipse is able to be more agile by updating only changed files on a remote WildFly server and redeploying if required.

Comment: I can recommend Adam Bien's WAD (Watch and Deploy) utility. Read my review here: https://rieckpil.de/review-improved-java-jakarta-ee-productivity-with-adam-biens-wad-watch-and-deploy/